# Variable declaration in if clause

Tags: java, if-statement, variable-declaration

```
if(someCondition)
  int a=10;//Compilation Error
else if(SomeOtherCondition){
int b=10;//no compilation Error
}
```

Why this happening.Why there is compilation error in first case. If i put braces then no compilation error but for if statement braces are optional if it's one statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define scope of the `int a` in `if statement` and it will be defined with curly braces `{}`.

```
if(someCondition){
  int a=10; // works fine
}else if(SomeOtherCondition){
  int b=10; //works fine
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(someCondition)
  int a=10;//Compilation Error - you have to define the scope of int. what scope does it have here? so {} are necessary
else if(SomeOtherCondition){
int b=10;//no compilation Error
}
```